# Could not increment identity;The column ID in table BATCH_JOB_SEQ does not allow null values

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I'm implementing Spring batch to read from a Sybase db,process and write to Sybase db back.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchConfig {

@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;


@Autowired
public DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
public JdbcCursorItemReader<DistanceFinderModel> reader(){
 JdbcCursorItemReader<DistanceFinderModel> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<DistanceFinderModel>();
 reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
 reader.setSql("SELECT * FROM distance_finder");
 reader.setRowMapper(new DistanceFinderRowMapper());
 
 return reader;
}

public class DistanceFinderRowMapper implements RowMapper<DistanceFinderModel>
{

      @Override
      public DistanceFinderModel mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException 
      {
          DistanceFinderModel data = new DistanceFinderModel();
          data.setBatch_id(rs.getString("batch_id"));
          data.setOrigin_lat(rs.getDouble("orig_lat"));
          data.setOrigin_long(rs.getDouble("orig_long"));
          data.setDest_lat(rs.getDouble("dest_lat"));
          data.setDest_long(rs.getDouble("dest_long"));
          data.setDistance(rs.getDouble("distance"));
          data.setPair_id(rs.getInt("pair_id"));
          return data;
      }
      
}

@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<DistanceFinderModel> writer(){
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<DistanceFinderModel> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<DistanceFinderModel>();
    writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    writer.setSql("INSERT INTO distance_finder 
(batch_id,origin_lat,origin_long,dest_lat,dest_long,distance,pair_id) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    writer.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(new PersonPreparedStatementSetter());
    return writer;
}

@Bean
public Processor processor(){
    return new Processor();
}

@Bean
public Step step1(){
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1"). <DistanceFinderModel,DistanceFinderModel>chunk(100)
.reader(reader()).processor(processor())
.writer(writer()).build();
}

@Bean
public Job exportPerosnJob(){
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("exportPeronJob").incrementer(new 
RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step1()).end().build();
}



}
```

Below is my controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/load")
public class LoadController {

@Autowired
JobLauncher jobLauncher;

@Autowired
Job job;

@GetMapping
public BatchStatus load() throws JobParametersInvalidException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, 
JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException {


    Map<String, JobParameter> maps = new HashMap<>();
    maps.put("time", new JobParameter(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    JobParameters parameters = new JobParameters(maps);
    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, parameters);

    System.out.println("JobExecution: " + jobExecution.getStatus());

    System.out.println("Batch is Running...");
    while (jobExecution.isRunning()) {
        System.out.println("...");
    }

    return jobExecution.getStatus();
}
}
```

Below is the error stack when I call the controller through browser request

```
com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: The column ID in table BATCH_JOB_SEQ does not allow null 
values.

at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.processEed(Tds.java:4003) ~[jconn4-1.0.jar:JDK 1.6/jdbcmain/Sun Jan 12 
09:45:05 PST 2014]
at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.nextResult(Tds.java:3093) ~[jconn4-1.0.jar:JDK 1.6/jdbcmain/Sun Jan 12 
09:45:05 PST 2014]
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ResultGetter.nextResult(ResultGetter.java:78) ~[jconn4-1.0.jar:JDK 
1.6/jdbcmain/Sun Jan 12 09:45:05 PST 2014]
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(SybStatement.java:289) ~[jconn4-1.0.jar:JDK 
1.6/jdbcmain/Sun Jan 12 09:45:05 PST 2014]
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(SybStatement.java:271) ~[jconn4-1.0.jar:JDK 
1.6/jdbcmain/Sun Jan 12 09:45:05 PST 2014]
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.updateLoop(SybStatement.java:2514) ~[jconn4-1.0.jar:JDK 
1.6/jdbcmain/Sun Jan 12 09:45:05 PST 2014]
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.executeUpdate(SybStatement.java:2498) ~[jconn4-1.0.jar:JDK 
1.6/jdbcmain/Sun Jan 12 09:45:05 PST 2014]
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.executeUpdate(SybStatement.java:576) ~[jconn4-1.0.jar:JDK 
1.6/jdbcmain/Sun Jan 12 09:45:05 PST 2014]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~ 
[na:1.8.0_144]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114) ~ 
[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.31.jar:na]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

I'm not sure what is happening here. Is this because I have a composite key in the table which I'm reading? or Is this because I have created the BATCH tables manually from the below script? I have removed ENGINE=InnoDB from all create statements as it was giving error in sybase.

```
CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE  (
JOB_INSTANCE_ID BIGINT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
VERSION BIGINT ,
JOB_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
JOB_KEY VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
constraint JOB_INST_UN unique (JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY)
)

CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION  (
JOB_EXECUTION_ID BIGINT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
VERSION BIGINT  ,
JOB_INSTANCE_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
CREATE_TIME DATETIME NOT NULL,
START_TIME DATETIME DEFAULT NULL ,
END_TIME DATETIME DEFAULT NULL ,
STATUS VARCHAR(10) ,
EXIT_CODE VARCHAR(2500) ,
EXIT_MESSAGE VARCHAR(2500) ,
LAST_UPDATED DATETIME,
JOB_CONFIGURATION_LOCATION VARCHAR(2500) NULL,
constraint JOB_INST_EXEC_FK foreign key (JOB_INSTANCE_ID)
references BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID)
)

CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS  (
JOB_EXECUTION_ID BIGINT NOT NULL ,
TYPE_CD VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL ,
KEY_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
STRING_VAL VARCHAR(250) ,
DATE_VAL DATETIME DEFAULT NULL ,
LONG_VAL BIGINT ,
DOUBLE_VAL DOUBLE PRECISION ,
IDENTIFYING CHAR(1) NOT NULL ,
constraint JOB_EXEC_PARAMS_FK foreign key (JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
references BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
)

CREATE TABLE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION  (
STEP_EXECUTION_ID BIGINT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
VERSION BIGINT NOT NULL,
STEP_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
JOB_EXECUTION_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
START_TIME DATETIME NOT NULL ,
END_TIME DATETIME DEFAULT NULL ,
STATUS VARCHAR(10) ,
COMMIT_COUNT BIGINT ,
READ_COUNT BIGINT ,
FILTER_COUNT BIGINT ,
WRITE_COUNT BIGINT ,
READ_SKIP_COUNT BIGINT ,
WRITE_SKIP_COUNT BIGINT ,
PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT BIGINT ,
ROLLBACK_COUNT BIGINT ,
EXIT_CODE VARCHAR(2500) ,
EXIT_MESSAGE VARCHAR(2500) ,
LAST_UPDATED DATETIME,
constraint JOB_EXEC_STEP_FK foreign key (JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
references BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
)
CREATE TABLE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT  (
STEP_EXECUTION_ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
SHORT_CONTEXT VARCHAR(2500) NOT NULL,
SERIALIZED_CONTEXT TEXT ,
constraint STEP_EXEC_CTX_FK foreign key (STEP_EXECUTION_ID)
references BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION(STEP_EXECUTION_ID)
) 

CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT  (
JOB_EXECUTION_ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
SHORT_CONTEXT VARCHAR(2500) NOT NULL,
SERIALIZED_CONTEXT TEXT ,
constraint JOB_EXEC_CTX_FK foreign key (JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
references BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
) 

CREATE TABLE BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ (
ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
UNIQUE_KEY CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
constraint UNIQUE_KEY_UN unique (UNIQUE_KEY)
) 

INSERT INTO BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ (ID, UNIQUE_KEY) select * from (select 0 
as ID, '0' as UNIQUE_KEY) as tmp where not exists(select * from 
BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_SEQ);

CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ (
ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
UNIQUE_KEY CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
constraint UNIQUE_KEY_UN unique (UNIQUE_KEY)
) 

INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ (ID, UNIQUE_KEY) select * from (select 0 
as ID, '0' as UNIQUE_KEY) as tmp where not exists(select * from 
BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ);

CREATE TABLE BATCH_JOB_SEQ (
ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
UNIQUE_KEY CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
constraint UNIQUE_KEY_UN unique (UNIQUE_KEY)
) 

INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_SEQ (ID, UNIQUE_KEY) select * from (select 0 as ID, '0' 
as UNIQUE_KEY) as tmp where not exists(select * from BATCH_JOB_SEQ);
```

Comment: I think that this was because of the script which I executed. I tried with another DATABASE by adding this configuration in properties spring.batch.schema=classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-sybase.sql

Answer (score 0):

I think that this was because of the script which I executed. I tried with another DATABASE by adding this configuration in properties spring.batch.schema=classpath:org/springframework/batch/core/schema-sybase.sql

Now the error is gone.